# How these two arrays vectors helping to get each element count?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

In the below code `b` and `c` are somehow are helping in getting the count of each element of `a` in calculating the sum. I can't grasp the logic behind it Please help.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,q,l,r;
    long long int ans=0;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&q);
    vector<int> a(n,0);
    vector<int> b(n+1,0);
    vector<int> c(n,0);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    while(q--)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&l,&r);
        b[l-1]++;
        b[r]--;
    }
    c[0]=b[0];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++) c[i]=c[i-1]+b[i];
    sort(c.begin(),c.end());
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ans+=a[i]*c[i];
    }
    printf("%lld",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Please explain how `b[]` and `c[]` are helping here.

[Link to problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFU)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note here is that the queries being made are 1-based, so

```
b[l-1]++;
b[r]--;
```

actually increment at the first index the inspector will want to review, and decrements the first value outside the range he wants to review.

Now, what `b` is doing is therefore keeping track of the range which the inspector is going to look through, so if we set `d[i] = sum(b[j]) for j < i`, we have `d[i] = 1` if the inspector is going to see this noodle pack, and `0` otherwise (for only 1 query). What `c` does is thus sum up all the different `d` from the queries by making it the sum of what came before (`c[i-1]`) and new information from `b`  (`b[i]`) (kind of like `c[i] = sum(d[i]) for all queries`.

If you still don't see it, think of it this way: when you add `b[i]`, and you were `0` before, and you just came up to a start of a new query, `b[i] = 1` and `c[i-1] = 0`. Now, `c[i] = 1`, and `b[i+1] = 0`, as you're still within the range. This will keep going until you hit `b[j] = -1`, we still have `c[j-1] = 1` but summing them up gets us back to `0`, and will keep `c[k] = 0` until a new query starts or ends. You can easily see that having extra changes in `b` within the same range will keep the logic valid.

Therefore `c[i]`shows us how many times the `i`-th noodle will be inspected. Sort and multiply by a sorted `a` to make sure you get the highest number of inspections with the highest quality and sum.

Hope this helps!